# Maintaining a current in a circuit connected to multiple DC motors (3.0V) that turn on and off arbitrarily

Tags: circuit-design, dc-motor, buck, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I have a circuit that is connected to multiple [DRV8833](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8833.pdf?ts=1619512016279&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) motor drivers. Each motor driver is connected to two 3.0V DC motors. The timing of when they run and stop and how many rotations they perform is very important for this purpose. When I try to run two or more motors at the same time, only a few actually turn and others are delayed by a lot. This is likely due to the sudden voltage drop caused by the first motor that runs without a problem.

Is it possible to solve this i.e. by using a [buck converter](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/LM2596HV-Converter-1-25V-26V-Step-Down-Regulator/dp/B07XJPDCK9/ref=sr_1_18?dchild=1&keywords=spannungsregler%203v&qid=1619589759&sr=8-18) like this one? At the moment I am simply using a USB wire directly connected to a power outlet, which is also not ideal for the 3V motors.

Comment: Power in = power out. A buck converter won't change this if your converter is sagging from excess power output. You need a bigger raw power source. Besides, you don't want to run high power loads through a converter if you don't have to anyways. Inefficient and complex. However, you say the problem is a delay which doesn't seem like power to me but you also don't get specific enough about what exactly is happening.

Comment: The delay is likely due to the increased power draw required whenever a motor is started,  which steadily drops as it starts turning, allowing the other motors to draw more current. Is there a better way to simply maintain a steady current in face of fluctuating motor usage? How do you calculate how man motors you can connect?

Answer (score 1):

- Measure the DC resistance, *R*, of one of your motors.
- Calculate the starting current using \$ I = \frac V R \$ where *V* is the supply voltage.
- Your power supply current rating should be ≥ \$In\$ where \$I\$ is the calculated current above and \$n\$ is the maximum number of motors to be run at any time.

Comment: What tools can I use to set the power supply current rating? I assume a USB power outlet is not enough for this, so would I need to purchase some sort of power source that still maintains 3V but has enough current to not drop whenever a motor is activated?

Comment: You just purchase a supply with the voltage rating you require and, as in my answer, with a current rating greater than or equal to the peak current requirement.

Comment: So if the resistance is 100ma and i connect two motors, the calculation would be 3/200= 0,015. a USB outlet has 500ma,but I am still having problems driving two motors simultaneously with this. Is there an error with my calculation?

Comment: @vuv resistance is measured in ohms, current in A or mA ... looks like you need to review some basics.

Comment: As danmcb says, the motor resistance should be measured and the result will be in ohms.